# Have a problem with cloudfront signed urls (No account found for the given parameters)

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create signed urls from cloudfront with aws-sdk-php

I have created both Distributions WEB and RTMP

and this is the code i used to do that

this is start.php

```
<?php


require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient;

$config = require('config.php');


// S3


$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'us-east-2',

]);

// CloudFront


$cloudfront = CloudFrontClient::factory([

    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'us-east-2',

]);
```

and this is config.php

```
<?php



return [

's3'=>[

    'key'       => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'secret'    => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'bucket'    => 'hdamovies',
    'region'    => 'us-east-2',

],

'cloudFront'    =>  [
    'url'   =>  'https://d2t7o0s69hxjwd.cloudfront.net',
],

];
```

and this is index.php

```
<?php



require 'config/start.php';


$video = 'XXXXXXXXXXX.mp4';
$expiry = new DateTime( '+1 hour' );

$url = $cloudfront->getSignedUrl([

    'private_key'   => 'pk-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem', 
    'key_pair_id'   => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'url'   => "{$config['cloudFront']['url']}/{$video}",
    'expires'   => strtotime('+10 minutes'),

]);


echo "<a href=".$url.">Downlod</a>";
```

When i click on the link i get that error

```
<Error>
<Code>KMS.UnrecognizedClientException</Code>
<Message>No account found for the given parameters</Message>
<RequestId>0F0A772FE67F0503</RequestId>


<HostId>juuIQZKHb1pbmiVkP7NVaKSODFYmBtj3T9AfDNZuXslhb++LcBsw9GNjpT0FG8MxgeQGqbVo+bo=</HostId></Error>
```

What is the problem here and how can i solve that?

Comment: Log into your AWS account immediately and disable the access-key-id `AKIAINT4GQEZJGR4GYTA`.  Unless you used a fictitious secret key, you have compromised these credentials by posting the secret key publicly.

Comment: I deleted it as soon as i posted the question

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Do you know the solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CloudFront does not support downloading objects that were stored, encrypted, in S3 using KMS Keys, apparently because the CloudFront Origin Access Identity is not an IAM user, so it's not possible to authorize it to have the necessary access to KMS.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=268390

Comment: how can i do it without kms?

Comment: The most common alternative is to use S3's built-in keys (SSE-S3). More details on server-side encryption can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/configuring-bucket-key.html

Comment: There is a newer CloudFront Origin Access Control that supports KMS.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-cloudfront-introduces-origin-access-control-oac/

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and had it resolved after setting up the correctly Identities. However, I had a lot of issues with the error even after setting things up correctly. This was because I was attempting to download a file that was originally uploaded when the bucket was KMS encrypted, then later when I changed it to SSE-S3, it still was throwing a KMS error.

After reuploading the file, it seemed to work without any issues. Hope this helps someone else